# How to ask about visiting hours (hospital)?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, articles

Can I use these patterns:

1. What ... visiting hours ... X hospital?
2. What time ... visiting hours ... X hospital?

I don't know what to put in the gaps:

What preposition should be before "X hospital"?

Does article "the" have to be before "visiting hours" or not?

Is it "is" or "are" that has to be in the first gap?

Answer (score 1):

For the preposition, you can use "at" or "for". I can't think of any difference between the two.

'The' is needed as you are talking about a specific instance of 'visiting hours' (The one for X hospital).

'Visiting hours' is plural so 'are' is required.

'What' doesn't sound as natural as 'what time' since you are asking about a time and not about what visiting hours are.

Putting it together: "What time are the visiting hours at X hospital?"

'What time' can be replaced for 'when': "When are the visiting hours for X hospital?"